# Problem creating a JSON file with an Array list

Tags: java, android, json

I'm creating a function which retrieves the installed apps of the device, the package of the app and the permissions each app has. The problem is that I want to put all of this into a JSON file and I do not know how to do it, here it is what I programmed, but it doesn't work, please, if someone know something, help, it is very important for me! Thanks in advance.

```
public static void installedApps(Context context) throws IOException{

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packagelist = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    CharSequence app;
    String pckge;
    String[] permissions;

    for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packagelist){

        app = applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager());
        pckge = applicationInfo.packageName;

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        Log.d("test", "App: "+ applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()) +", Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);

        try{
            PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

            //Get Permissions
            String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

            if(requestedPermissions != null){
                for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++){

                    Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);

                    permissions = requestedPermissions;

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                    try{
                        json.put("app", app);
                        json.put("package", pckge);

                        jsonArray.put(Integer.parseInt("permission"), permissions);


                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }
            //primero cargar en un array todos los datos, y pasarlos a un json llamandolos
        }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? How are you trying to return/store the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably go for something like this:

```
public static void installedApps(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo> packagelist = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    JSONObject resp = new JSONObject();

    for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packagelist) {

        CharSequence app = applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager());
        String pckge = applicationInfo.packageName;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            //Get Permissions
            PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
            if (requestedPermissions != null) {
                json.put("app", app);
                json.put("package", pckge);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (String requestedPermission : requestedPermissions) {
                    jsonArray.put(requestedPermission);
                }
                json.put("permission", jsonArray);
                resp.put(applicationInfo.name, json); // something to identify each app
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // return resp.toString() or store in file or whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it, now the problem I'm receiving is that when i want to store the json i receive this: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/app.json (Permission denied), I want to create a json file and write it, could you pls help me?

Comment: Sure, I would need to see the code so you could post a different question to get an answer there. Meanwhile, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37819550/java-io-filenotfoundexception-storage-emulated-0-new-file-txt-open-failed-ea or https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files for common problems with reading/writing files. I'm pretty sure it's related to some permissions missing, but without a code sample it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, this is the code 
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "app.json");



                            try(FileWriter File = new FileWriter(file)){

                                File.write(json.toString());
                                File.flush();

                            }catch (IOException e){

                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }

I'm struggling so hard, so if you could help me it would be perfect!!

Comment: Again, this should be discussed in another question but I'll give some general tips: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your manifest, implement runtime permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html or or you can manually enable the storage permission by going to settings>apps> "your_app_name" >click on it >then click permissions> then enable the storage (use this only for debugging)

Answer (score 0):

I am petty sure there is a problem with this line,

```
permissions = requestedPermissions;
```

...

```
jsonArray.put(Integer.parseInt("permission"), permissions);
```

since you define the `permissions` array at the top,  you will see the final `requestPermission` entry adding to `jsonArray` over and over `packageList.size()` times.

bring `permission` to inside the loop. it will solve your problem.

Comment: I managed to do that, the problem now is that when I debug the program, it always show me this in the json:  {"app":"Filter Provider","package":"com.samsung.android.provider.filterprovider","permissions":"[Ljava.lang.String;@e64a639"}. The problem is that I do not want the Ljava.lang.String, I want a list, do you know anything about this issue?

Comment: @CesarSanchez `permissions` is as `String[]` and you are adding it as an Object, that's why it internally calls `toString()` method which returns the string you are seeing. See my answer, try `for (String requestedPermission : requestedPermissions) { jsonArray.put(requestedPermission);}` and it should work

Comment: Sure. This is what happens when to try to convert an array directly in to a string. If you are using java 8 try,  String.join(",", permissions); or something to convert a string array in to String. Then you will be fine.

Comment: @cesarSanchez if you got it working don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @lakshans Thanks, I managed to do it, now the problem I'm receiving is that when i want to store the json i receive this: W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/app.json (Permission denied), I want to create a json file and write it, could you pls help me?

Comment: You can find the answer to your problem in different questions in stack overflow try this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724540/write-data-in-json-file-in-right-form-java